# ClassCastException de RSAPublicKey a CaviumRSAPublicKey

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

tengo una exception al realizar un Cast, micodigo es el siguiente:

```
public static RSAPublicKey getKey(String filename)
            throws Exception {

            byte[] keyBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filename));

            X509EncodedKeySpec spec =
              new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
            KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            return (RSAPublicKey)kf.generatePublic(spec);
    }
```

Aquí cargo la llave publica y la carga con éxito.
Después tengo el casteo de la siguiente manera:

```
RSAPublicKey pubKey = (RSAPublicKey) GeneraKeysRsa.getKey(file);
CaviumRSAPublicKey key = (CaviumRSAPublicKey) pubKey;
```

Intento realizar el casteo pero obtengo lo siguiente:

```
ClassCastException: sun.security.rsa.RSAPublicKeyImpl cannot be cast to com.cavium.key.CaviumRSAPublicKey
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Buscando la documentación de ambas partes encontré lo siguiente:
[Aquí](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/interfaces/RSAPublicKey.html) vemos que hereda de PublicKey RSAPublicKey que a su vez hereda de Key, después CaviumRSAPublicKey hereda de CaviumRSAKey y esta a su vez de CaviumKey, esta a la vez hereda de Key entonces no debería haber problema al realizar el casteo dado que se esta haciendo un Key con otro Key.

UPDATE 1
El tema va así, tengo una llave RSA pública, esta la cargo para poder realizar "x" cifrado, pero esta la debo ingresar en un [HSM](https://aws.amazon.com/es/cloudhsm/), es especifico el que ofrece Amazon, esto por temas de seguridad, para no estar teniendo que cargar la llave desde X lado, sino consultarla directamente desde el HSM, pero esta debe ser Cavium para poder almacenarla en el HSM, es por eso que intento realizar el casteo pero no he tenido éxito hasta el momento.

Me podrían decir por que me sale esa exception.
Gracias y saludos.

Comment: Hola @5frags donde encontraste que "CaviumRSAPublicKey hereda de CaviumRSAKey y esta a su vez de CaviumKey  esta a la vez hereda de Key " ?

Comment: @Jorgesys me puse a decompilar el cliente .jar de Amazon y ahí pude ver lo que te digo, agrego una foto a la pregunta.

Answer (score 2):

**Lo que comentas en realidad no es posible, en realidad debes obtener una `RSAPublicKey` que sea instancia de `CaviumRSAPublicKey`**, si esto es así entonces puedes obtener/definir propiedades:

```
    if(pubKey instanceof CaviumRSAPublicKey) {
            CaviumRSAPublicKey cavRSAPublicKey = (CaviumRSAPublicKey) pubKey;
      ...
      ...
      ...
   }
```

Este es un ejemplo de como obtener una `RSAPublicKey` con el proveedor  `"Cavium"` :

```
   KeyPairGenerator keyPairGen;

    try {        
      //Create an instance of the provider Cavium.
      keyPairGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "Cavium");          
      //Generate the Key pair. 
      keyPairGen.initialize(new CaviumRSAKeyGenParameterSpec(keySize, exponent));
      KeyPair kp = keyPairGen.generateKeyPair();
      if (kp == null) {
        System.out.println("Error creating keypair!.");
      }

      //Generate RSA Key Pair.
      RSAPrivateKey privKey = (RSAPrivateKey) kp.getPrivate();
      RSAPublicKey pubKey = (RSAPublicKey) kp.getPublic();
      System.out.println("Generated RSA Key Pair with Cavium provider!.");


    if(pubKey instanceof CaviumRSAPublicKey) {
            CaviumRSAPublicKey cavRSAPublicKey = (CaviumRSAPublicKey) pubKey;

            // Save the public key handle. You'll need this to perform future encryption and decryption operations.
            System.out.println("Public Key Handle = " + cavRSAPublicKey.getHandle());

            // Get the public key label generated by the SDK.       
            System.out.println("Public Key Label = " + cavRSAPublicKey.getLabel());

            // Get the Extractable property of the public key.
            System.out.println("Is Public Key Extractable = " +cavRSAPublicKey.isExtractable());

            // Get the Persistent property of the public key.
            System.out.println("Is Public Key Persistent = " + cavRSAPublicKey.isPersistent());                      

            // Verify the key type and size.
            System.out.println("Public Key Algorithm : " + cavRSAPublicKey.getAlgorithm());
            System.out.println("Public Key Size : " + cavRSAPublicKey.getSize());
          }

      } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException e) {
         System.out.println("NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException" + e.getMessage());
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
         System.out.println("InvalidAlgorithmParameterException" + e.getMessage());

    }
```

Comment: Ya he seguido toda la documentación de Amazon, pero no encuentro forma de hacerlo, voy actualizar mi pregunta dando mas detalles.

Answer (score 1):

La relación "es-un" va de subclases a superclases, pero no al revés (y desde luego no naturalmente).

Pongamos un ejemplo servicio: `Number` como superclase, y `Float` e `Integer` como subclases.

Una instancia de `Integer` será siempre una instancia de `Number`, ya que `Integer` es una subclase de `Number`. Pero esa instancia no es una clase de `Float`. No tiene porqué tener los métodos definidos en `Float`, y usará siempre los métodos de `Integer` (ya sean definidos en `Integer`, o heredados de `Number` o `Integer`).

Poniendo el ejemplo en la naturaleza, `Gato` y `Perro` son subclases de `Mamífero`. Puedes asignar un gato a una variable tipo `Mamífero`, porque lo es. Pero no puedes asignar un gato a una variable de tipo `Perro`, porque no lo es. Cualquier gato es un mamífero, pero no todos los mamíferos son gatos.

Comment: Entiendo tu punto, pero aquí habría forma de realizar un cast? Ya me he dado topes contra la pared y nada.

Comment: No. Tienes que crear una instancia de `CaviumPublicKey` (o subclase), ya sea porque tiene un constructor que te permita "copiar" los datos de un `RSAPublicKey` o directamente (p.ej https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/cloudhsm/latest/userguide/java-sample-manage-keys.html). Por cierto, las clases `sun.*` no son del standard Java sino de la implementación del JVM de Sun y no tienes garantizado que estén en otras implementaciones.

Comment: he actualizado mi pregunta.

Comment: La pregunta sigue sin estar bien dirigida. El cast de `sun.[...].RSAPublicKey` a `CaviumRSAPublicKey` no va a funcionar y el `ClassCastException` no se puede eliminar, tienes que crear el objeto `CaviumRSAPublicKey`. ¿Estás seguro de que has seguido los pasos del manual? ¿Incluyendo especificar el provider criptográfico? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/cloudhsm/latest/userguide/use-cavium-provider.html

Comment: El provider ya fue agregado